# RVM rails version not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, rhel5

I have just downloaded rvm to manage my ruby versioning. I have created a new gemset and installed rails 2.3.8.   gem list shows the following gems

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.8)  
actionpack (2.3.8)  
activerecord (2.3.8) 
activeresource (2.3.8)  
activesupport (2.3.8)  
rack (1.1.0)  
rails (2.3.8) 
rake (0.8.7)
```

But when i run sudo script/server I get the following error:

> Missing the Rails 2.3.8 gem. Please
>   `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`, update
>   your RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in
>   config/environment.rb for the Rails
>   version you do have installed, or
>   comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use
>   the latest version installed.

Am I missing something? why am I unable to start the ror webrick server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run this as root, in fact that is most likely why this is breaking.  RVM is running as your user, so when you do "sudo" script/server its looking at the gems installed in the context of root, not as your user.

Just do script/server and you should be fine.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, I need to keep the permissions as is and I don't have access to run script/server under my user.  Do I need to install system wide rvm then? to use as root?

Comment: If you can successfully install rvm, how is it you can't run script/server?